Why expectation term in VAE loss not implemented in practical?
According to VAE paper : https://arxiv.org/pdf/1906.02691 (eq 2.10, page 21)
VAE loss contain the expectation term. If I understand correctly, we need sample more than 1 result from an input x and average it's loss to satisfy the expectation term. But I find many implementation that just only sample one result, but why?

Though only using one sample will have a high variance, its expectation is still correct; this is a broader issue beyond VAEs and you may want to use search terms like "Monte Carlo Approximation", "Stochastic Gradient Descent" or "Finite Sum Problem".

@JohnMadden it's very helpful, thanks a lot.
